# angular expressions do not work inside the controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller

I am facing a strange problem with the below code..

whenever I remove the ng-controller="page" from the body tag, the expressions start getting evaluated. But on applying this controller on body tag, the expressions tend to get printed as text rather than being evaluated.

Below is my relevant code ([Snippet](http://www.chopapp.com/#q8ns04o7)):

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <!-- links removed for brevity -->
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app',[]);
            app.controller('page',function($scope){
                $scope.segment.name = 'asdf';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="page" style="padding:0px;">
        <!-- additional markup removed for brevity -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Portal ID" ng-model="page.segment.name"/>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Search {{page.segment.name}}</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am possibly making some blunder in the above code as the below code which I wrote as proof of concept works well.

POC code ([Snippet](http://www.chopapp.com/#puu8r9bt)):

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <!-- links removed for brevity -->
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="page">
        <a>Name : {{page.segment.name}}</a>
        <input type = "text" ng-model="page.segment.name"/>
    </body>
    <!-- links removed for brevity -->
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('page',['$scope',function($scope){}]);
    </script>
</html>
```

Kindly help
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check out [MCVE]. Posts that just contain links are frowned upon because what happens when that link dies in the future? Now your question can't be used for reference by someone else with a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting an error in the console. I would guess it's something similar to "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined." What you are doing here is not valid:

```
$scope.segment.name = 'asdf';
```

You need to either do this:

```
$scope.segment = {};
$scope.segment.name = 'asdf';
```

Or this:

```
$scope.segment = { name: 'asdf' };
```

You have to create the `segment` object explicitly before you attempt to set properties on it.